# Unable to send CTRL + SPACE Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, action

I am unable to send CTRL + SPACE to the browser using Actions class. I tried this

```
Thread.sleep(1500);         

action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0020')).perform();          
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            action.release();
```

But it is not running properly. Please help. I Just want to send CTRL + SPACE.

Comment: Could you please let us to know in what environment you meet the problem (Browser, OS). Also please provide site or html where you try send the keys,

Comment: Have you tried using `Robot` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using robot class....

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
```

Hope this helps you ...kindly get back if u have any queries...

Comment: Thank you so much for your Answer. I have found another way to implement the same. But if i get time i will surely try this out.